# C++ Search Algorithms - Processing Huge Data

Tags: c++, winapi, search

I have a code that searches in files for a string, File(s) can be 1mg of size or 1gig or bigger.

I get the file data with `ReadFile()` WinAPI and Convert into Hex, Then search for a string (Which is hexed before) in the Converted Data.

I used this code for search (string search):

```
std::string searchStr = "48656C6C6FA"
std::string fileData = ToHex(inputString);

if(fileData.find(searchStr, 0) != std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << FileName;
}
```

It takes almost **11** sec to search for string in **2900** files.

Is there any other search algorithm or function to be faster? This way (above) sometimes missed the string and not perfectly works.

Comment: How about not converting it to hex?

Comment: I don't understand the `ToHex(inputString);`. Wouldn't it be faster to convert the `searchStr` the opposite direction? It's probably much smaller than the `fileData`. Btw. the latter has to be done only once for all files...

Comment: And why you avoided regular expressions?

Comment: *Convert into Hex* - this is for what ?

Comment: @UKMonkey I also use `.exe` and ' `.dll'` for search. It's need to be convert to hex otherwise search process takes null-terminated and exit.

Comment: @MatteoRagni Well using regex could as easily [*add* a problem](https://xkcd.com/1171/) as take it away.

Comment: and main here can be not how you search some data in memory buffer, but how you enumerate and read files

Comment: The advantage of a `std::string` is that it can contain/consider even `'\0'` bytes as the length is stored separately. The only exception: You shouldn't count on the result of `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: @RbMm I should convert into Hex because of the search string in executable files.

Comment: @Scheff That's true of a `std::vector<uint8_t>` as well.

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin - nothing understand. *executable files* and so what ?? the type of files at all no play any role

Comment: Considering that `std::string` (as well as `std::vector<uint8_t>`) can handle 0-bytes correctly I see no necessity for the "Convert to Hex".

Comment: @RbMm I use `ReadFile` and get the file's data in binary mode, then put it into char[] and finally string, The `exe` file has `NULL` character so search process can't search anymore after 1 null-terminated character and read only 4 first characters of the file.

Comment: As well as converting to hex being a performance hog, it will get the answer wrong.  Consider search for the byte "AB" in "0A B0" - it will find a match half-way through the first byte!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The `std::string` would provide the required `std::string::find()` which might be an optimized version for string search. Don't know about `std::vector<uint8_t>`. Do you have something in mind out of `<algorithm>`?

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin - *I use ReadFile and get the file's data in binary mode* - and in this mode you and need search. you not need any convertations

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin: You have to use the right constructor to get the nul bytes into a string, but it is very easy.  `const char *buffer = ???; size_t buflen = ???; std::string binaryText {buffer, buflen};` will give you a string contain the binary contents of `buffer`.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Given that the search string is 11 nibbles, having half-matches seems to be intentional.

Comment: I believe the "half byte" is a dead path. Looks like an error in the conversion. I believe the last hex number must be acutally "0A" - the newline character which accidentally was appended without leading 0. But, it's just my assumption...

Comment: The idea with the broken "0A" came from the preceding hex digits where I can see the "Hello" in...

Comment: @Scheff Oh good grief!  I had assumed it was a sloppy copy-and-paste.  Well that will cause all sorts of interesting effects!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a smaller file (like a few megabytes, or even a couple of hundred megabytes, depending on the amount of memory your system have) then read it all into memory, otherwise I recommend using *memory mapped files*. If the file is to big to be mapped you can use a sliding window or double-buffering algorithm to read blocks of the data from the file into memory.

Then to search for a specific sequence of bytes, you do a linear search through the contents of the file, looking for the *first* byte of the sequence you search for (in the case of `0x48656C6C6FA` that's `0xFA`) . If found then you attempt to match the second byte in the sequence (in the example that's `0xC6`) to the next byte from the file, and so on until you have matched the whole sequence.

If the second (or continuing) byte doesn't match, you continue your search for the first byte.

This has O(n) complexity, where `n` is the number of bytes in the file. Unless you know beforehand that the data you search for is in a specific part of the file, that's the best you're going to get.

---

If the files exists on an SSD you can use threads to search, one thread per file. ***But*** not all 2900 files at once, that will swamp the processor. Instead have 4-8 threads doing the search (depending on the number of cores of your system), and as soon as one thread is finished with a file, then it takes the next.

Can't be used on a spinning-disk drive, as it will thrash the disk while the heads are seeking back and forth as the threads are trying to read.

Comment: better base not on thread count but on simultaneous io requests count. recently test this solution on nvme disk - got the best results when we have ~32  simultaneous io requests. but this of course very depend from disk. and instead threads which do synchronous io, use asynchronous io requests

Answer (score 3):

Speed: use a memory mapped file

Accuracy: use std::search using binary values.

e.g.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

// some function to return a pointer to the first byte in the file and the length 
extern std::tuple<const std::uint8_t*, std::size_t> get_file_bounds();

int main()
{
    auto [begin, size] = get_file_bounds();
    auto search_string = std::vector<std::uint8_t> {
        0x48,
        0x65,
        0x6C,
        0x6C,
        0x6F
    };

    auto iter = std::search(begin, begin + size, 
                            search_string.begin(), search_string.end());

    if (iter != begin + size)
    {
        // found the sequence 
    }
    else 
    {
        // didn't find it
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For search strings as short as the ones you have (5 1/2 bytes apparently), the bottleneck will often be the disk I/O. I suspect that those 2900 files may be on a harddisk. That would translate to roughly 4 ms per file, which is quite decent.

Sure, the conversion to hex may be a bit clumsy, but given the 5 1/2 bytes (11 hex digits) it might not be entirely unreasonable. I.e. you might not get a major speed improvement if the HDD is the real bottleneck.

So to check, measure how much time you spend if you *don't* search in the 2900 fies, and just read them in. Don't even convert them to hex. No matter how smart the search algorithm, the time you'll need for disk I/O is a lower bound. If this isn't good enough, get a fast SSD.

Comment: if use ssd /NVMe disk, exist sense you asynchronous io (for both enumerate folders/read files) hor have many read request at once. this give be very big advantage in search speed

Comment: The I/O hardware is not in my hand, users have different PCs.

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin at which point there's nothing you can do to make it faster than loading all the files and doing nothing. If the rest of the program is 1% rather than 0.001% of that time, no-one will care

Answer (score 1):

For a faster string search algorithm, take a look at the Boyer Moore search algorithm. Boost (and c++17) has such an implementation.

Also, avoid converting the file into hex (std::strings can contain '\0' characters).

And if you file IO is limiting, memory mapped files might be the way forward..

Answer (score 1):

While this is probably a storage bottleneck problem there are string search algorithms that can be significantly faster than linear, for example Boyer Moore (described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm ), they do require processing the search pattern and ave some memory overhead compared to a linear search.

The basic idea is to know how many characters can be skipped based on what you find at a given index. (i.E. start at fileData[patternLLen-1] and if the character isn't even in the search pattern you can next look at fileData[patternLen+patternLen-1] and so on.

The longer your pattern the more likely such an algorithm is to be an improvement over a straight linear search. The boost library already has implementations of several such improved string search algorithms (found in boost/algorithm\searching/).